# Adding rows and columns to data.frame in R

Tags: r

I am struggling with the use of data frames.

I am calculating test results for n participants and each participant has m results. This will be done in nested for loops: n x m.
So first For-Loop goes into 1st Proband. Second for loop calculates the test values. The test-result for 1 test for 1 proband is returned from a function.

In the end I would like to have a table like this:
[image]

I struggle setting this up with data frames and vectors as I am completely new to R.

Pseudo Code:

```
final_results[][]

for (each folder in path) {
  proband_results[]
  for (each file in folder) {
    test_result <- someFunction(file)
    proband_results.append(test_result)
  }
  final_results.append(proband_results)
}
```

Comment: Can you provide your input datasets?

Comment: Sorry, not exactly sure what input datasets you mean. I  have a function which I give a path. It will get all Folders in that path (each folder is 1 proband). For every folder it will get all files (each file is 1 test), now it will calculate the test value out of the file. I am in need of dynamically building up a resulting dataframe.

Comment: I've tried adding some pseudo code to show what I want to achieve in R.

Comment: Ah okay! So i can just use cbind for adding new test results (as they are new colums) and to append it to the final results i can use rbind (as each proband is a new row in the resulting table). I would like to stick to data.frames as that seems to be the "right" way. How do I initialize them so I can later append to them in the for loops?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the R version based on your code. Initializing with `NULL` and using `cbind` and `rbind`. I am assuming the `test_result` is already a data.frame type.

```
final_results= NULL

for (each folder in path) {
  proband_results = NULL
  for (each file in folder) {
    test_result <- someFunction(file)
    proband_results = cbind(proband_results,test_result)  # column bind 
  }
  final_results = rbind(final_results,proband_results) # row bind
}
```

However, this is not an efficient way in R to combine result. Because, for example, here you are calling `rbind` n times, where everytime the growing final_results are called (growing memory) and using `rbind`. A vectorized way is (small improvement) to use `list` structure (linked list):

```
final_results= NULL
i = 1
for (each folder in path) {
  proband_results = NULL
  for (each file in folder) {
    test_result <- someFunction(file)
    proband_results = cbind(proband_results,test_result)  # column bind 
  }
  final_results[[i]] = proband_results # A list that link all proband results
  i = i + 1
}

res = do.call("rbind",final_results)  # rbind for all the element in the list
```

This version does `rbind` once for all.

Answer (score 2):

As advised in [Circle 2 of the R Inferno: Growing Objects](https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf), do not expand especially larger objects like matrices/arrays and data frames in a loop using `cbind`, `rbind`, `append`, and `c` operators which leads to excessive copying in memory.

Instead, build lists of objects and then bind in one call outside of iterations. Alternatively, initialize a large empty container and iteratively assign values by indexes of container without appending.

For the former, the approach can be facilitated with R's *apply* family loops known to output objects of equal length to input. Below runs `sapply` for files nested in a larger `lapply` for subfolders. *Somefunction* is assumed to receive one argument being file name and to return a vector.

```
# GET TOP LEVEL SUBFOLDERS 
subfolders <- list.dirs(path="/my/root/path", recursive=FALSE)

# ITERATE THROUGH ALL FILES OF EACH FOLDER
master_list <- lapply(subfolders, function(f) {

    tmp_files <- list.files(path=f, pattern=".ext", full.names=TRUE)
    sapply(tmp_files, someFunction)                    # RETURNS MATRIX

})

final_obj <- do.call(rbind, master_list)               # MASTER MATRIX
```